# How to reduce Heroku slug size when deploying NestJS from monorepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, nestjs, monorepo

I have a monorepo containing a NestJS app, which I am attempting to deploy to Heroku. It is failing on deploy due to exceeding max slug size of 500MB.

My monorepo has 5 Angular apps, a few Node servers (Loopback4, Express and NestJS), and a few shared libraries.  The root level package.json contains - as one would expect in a monorepo - an accumulation of all dependencies from all projects.  As expected too then, the node_modules folder is large (in my case exceeding 1.2GB).

I have set up my NestJS app to deploy to Heroku by pushing the entire repository, and then using Procfiles to identify where the NestJS is located, building and running, etc..

These are the build packs I need (can't do without them):

```
heroku/nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
```

However when I attempt to deploy to Heroku via CLI - it fails with the error of

```
remote: -----> Compressing...        
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 522.3M is too large (max is 500M).        
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

It feels as thought there a a few approaches I  could follow - but none of them appeal to me:

1. create another remote repo containing just this NestJS server (but I have it depending on other shared libs in the mono)
2. Find a way to have this NestJS contain its own package.json (but then what is the point of a monorepo)
3. Pay Heroku for a higher spec package to get a larger slug size maximum (but as a hobby developer with a pretty small NestJS server - why shouldn't Eco dynos be sufficient?)

I am also not quite sure if the problem is the size of `node_modules` on Heroku - or rather the size of code/dependencies/build_packs (I guess this is the slug though).

I have a lot of hobby/playground projects with a lot of dependencies (and don't want to be limited by this). But I also don't see why the `node_modules` on Heroku needs to have @loopback and @angular libraries included in it (I have already reviewed the NestJS dependencies and removed unnecessary ones).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: A monorepo doesn't necessarily require you to install all dependencies for everything all of the time. For example, NPM's workspaces let you do e.g. `npm --workspace one-ws install` to install only what that one workspace needs. Alternatively Heroku supports Docker containers, which would give you a lot more control over exactly what's in and out.

Comment: ok thank you. i will try the ```--workspace``` - it certainly makes sense